Image of a $C^1$ manifold
Let $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ be a $C^1$ map with $n, l >0$. It's well know that $F(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is not necessarily a $C^1$ manifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n+l}$. Then what about the following proposition? Is it true?
Proposition: Let $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ be a $C^1$ map with $n, l >0$. Then there's countably many $n$-dimensional $C^1$ submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^{n+l}$, denoted by $N_i$, such that $F(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset \cup_{i=1}^\infty N_i$.
When $F$ is a Lipschitz map, it's known that we can an addtional $N_0 \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+l}$ with $\mathcal{H}^n(N_0)=0$ such that $F(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset \cup_{i=0}^\infty N_i$.  Then will $N_0$ be removed if $F$ is $C^1$?
